# Is indexing necessary for "exists" filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it required to index a `keyword` field with potentially infinite unique values (such as a `website` field) if all I ever do with is to query for its existence?

I have a dataset of restaurant data and user reviews as follows:

```py
mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "text", "index": True},
        "openDate": {"type": "date", "index": True},
        "numReviews": {"type": "integer", "index": True},
        "priceRange": {"type": "keyword", "index": True},
        "description": {"type": "text", "index": True},

        # Some other fields
        # ...
        # ...


        "website": {"type": "keyword", "index": False}
    }
}
```

Of all things being equal, we want to boost restaurants with a website.

I have the following logic to search for a restaurant for a multi-term query `query` in fields `_fields`. Additionally, I have a few `should` filters that boost the score.

```js
_query = {
        bool: {
          must: {
            multi_match: {
              query,
              fields: _fields,
            },
          },

          should: [
            {
              exists: {
                field: 'description',
                boost: 5,
              },
            },
            {
              exists: {
                field: 'website',
                boost: 5,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };
```

In this case, do I need to change `index=False` to `index=True` for `website` field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

although the documentation clearly says that the `exists` query doesn't work on fields with an `"index": false` mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#query-dsl-exists-query), it does work in my 7.13.1 environment. However, I would recommend you to trust the documentation on this, for future compatibility.

What I would recommend you to do to avoid indexing all the website values is to create a new boolean field `websiteExist` at index time and query that one while keeping `"index": false` disabled for `website`